# How do I undo a prior commit though leave everything afterwards intact using Git?

Tags: git

I deleted some files some time ago that I need back. I'm using Git.

How do I undo a commit that was done some time ago and leave everything else since then as is?

Comment: Why not just checkout the old version and add/commit the missing files again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
git revert <revision>
```

Just find the sha1 revision ID in your `git log` that you want to undo, and this will make a commit which is the opposite, thereby undoing the old commit.

Comment: +1. Probably only works if that commit contained nothing else except the deleted files, though.